# Im getting this error while working in javascript ... Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-5, popover

When I try to initialize popovers, I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function.
```

I have included the Bootstrap 5 links and jquery link, but for some reason, it is still not working. I am unsure why this error is occurring and would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**And this is my Html popover button**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="popcart" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="bottom"> Cart(<span id="carting">0</span>)</button>
```

**And this is how i  initialize my popover**

```
//initialize popovers
    
    $("#popcart").popover();
    updatePopover(bag);


    function updatePopover(bag) {
        console.log('We are inside updatePopover');
        var popStr = "";
        popStr = popStr + "<h5> Cart for your items in my shopping cart </h5><div class='mx-2 my-2'>";
        var i = 1;
        for (var item in bag) {
            popStr = popStr + "<b>" + i + "</b>. ";
            popStr = popStr + document.getElementById('name' + item).innerHTML.slice(0, 19) + "... Qty: " + bag[item] + '<br>';
            i = i + 1;
        }
        popStr = popStr + "</div>"
        console.log(popStr);
        document.getElementById('popcart').setAttribute('data-bs-content', popStr);
        $('#popcart').popover('show');
    }
```

**When I click on the + (plus) or - (minus) button to update my cart, the popover that shows all the products in my cart does not update to reflect the changes. The popover only updates when I refresh the page, which is not ideal. I would like to see all the values in the popover as soon as the popover appears on the screen, without having to refresh the page. Can you help me troubleshoot this issue?**

**And these codes are for cart and  '+' and '-' buttons**

```
    function updateCart(bag) {
        console.log("here")
        for (var item in bag) {
            document.getElementById('div' + item).innerHTML = "<button id='minus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary minus'>-</button> <span id='val" + item + "''>" + bag[item] + "</span> <button id='plus" + item + "' class='btn btn-primary plus'> + </button>";
        }
        localStorage.setItem('bag', JSON.stringify(bag));
        document.getElementById('carting').innerHTML = Object.keys(bag).length;
        //console.log('here')
        updatePopover(bag);
    }

//this is my minus button
    $('.divpr').on('click', "button.minus", function () {

        a = event.target.id.slice(7,);//extracting the number
        bag['pr' + a] = bag['pr' + a] - 1;
        bag['pr' + a] = Math.max(0, bag['pr' + a])//will return max value if will not go below 0
        document.getElementById('valpr' + a).innerHTML = bag['pr' + a];
        updateCart(bag);
    })


//this is my plus button 

    $('.divpr').on('click', "button.plus", function () {
        a = event.target.id.slice(6,)
        bag['pr' + a] = bag['pr' + a] + 1
        document.getElementById('valpr' + a).innerHTML = bag['pr' + a];
        updateCart(bag);
    })
```

**I tried this to enable popover still it is not working**

```
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

[image: This is my homepage]

Comment: @xyresCould you please explain how to initialize popovers in Bootstrap 5 and how I can call my updatePopover(bag) function outside of the function where it is defined? Currently, I am only able to call this function from inside of other functions and not directly. I would appreciate any guidance on how to ensure that this function is accessible from the global scope.

Comment: I was wrong. You can use jQuery with BS5 ([see docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery)). I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#optionally-using-jquery), when Bootstrap 5 detects jQuery in the window, it injects its components as jQuery plugins.

I think the problem here is that you're calling the Bootstrap component (`popover`) before it has been injected into jQuery namespace.

You should make all the initialization calls after jQuery's `ready` event:

This seems to work (see live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/esab19hu/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#popcart').popover();
});
```

---

**Sidenote:** If you're including `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`, you don't need to include `popper.min.js`. It's already bundled in the Bootstrap script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is now working perfectly. However, Im not  using jQuery, but simple JavaScript. I had been stuck on this issue for the past 2 days.